# How to turn on syntax highlighting for vim

Tags: vim

Whenever I try editing code in vim, every character is completely grey.
My `~/.vimrc` has `syntax on` and `filetype plugin on` included.

I noticed that I didn't have a `~/.vim/colors/` folder and then downloaded a colorscheme (monokai.vim) and put it in this directory. The problem was not fixed.

When typing `:colo <SPACE> <TAB>` vim does not return anything.

I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution to this.

Comment: open a file that should have a color syntax and see what `set ft=?` says

Comment: It says `E474: Invalid argument: ft=?`

Comment: my bad it should be `set ft?`

Comment: It says `filetype=python`

Comment: You need ``set nocompatible`` and ``syntax enable`` too.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? So syntax off then syntax on?

Comment: Neither of these worked for me

Comment: You have to put
```syntax enable```
and
```colorscheme monokai```
to your vimrc

Comment: @ThomasDehaeze I tried this as well with no luck

Comment: Can you show us your `vimrc` file ?
Moreover, can you show us the output of the following command `tree -d -L 2` (inside your .vim folder)

Comment: At this point, after having installed a newer version of Vim, I am no longer encountering the problem. Thanks for your help.